# Modify asp file

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I'm using WIX toolset 3.5 to create msi package for installing web site. My web site is asp based and i have configuration in config.asp file.
When installing I have dialog window for user to insert server name, database name, user name and password.
Then I have to insert(replace) this values into config.asp file.
I have several lines like:
ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Password=xxx; User ID=user;Initial Catalog=....

What is the best way to do that? I have to parse file some way.
Any example? All I have found were how to replace config file in .NET, which is xml based and has different approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If config.asp files aren't true XML that can be processed using XPATH, you'll have to write custom actions to do the updates.   FWIW, InstallShield has a "text replacements" feature that is similar to the Xml capabilities but uses search and replace on regular text.

Comment: Thank you. I'm familiar with custom actions, but do you have some example of install shield text replacements?

Comment: With InstallShield, you use a designer to program so it's not easy to post an "example".  Here is the help topic: http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield16helplib/TextFileChanges-SrchRplc.htm

Comment: I decided to go with WIX and CustomAction:

String filePath=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "config.asp";

But the file doesn't exists in temp folder. I have After="InstallInitialize"
InstallExecuteSequence. 

What I'm doing wrong? Where I can access the file with custom action?
Should i use After="InstallFiles" and change the file from install location and not temp location?